# C# Httpwebrequest - get table data below link

Tags: c#, visual-studio, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack, httpwebresponse

Okay so I'm trying to select innertext from a  tag which is 2 below the a tag containing specified string

Example of html:

```
<td align="left"><a href="#">
Example String
</a></td>
<td align="right">132</td>
<td align="right">89</td>
<td align="right">123</td>
```

I want second TD below " Example String within the ahref tag:

```
<td align="right">89</td>
```

I know if i do:

```
//a[contains(., 'Example String')]
```

this will successfully identify the a href containing Example String using SelectNode but then I want to grab the inner text from the 2nd td tag below that

I tried,

```
//a[contains(., 'Example String')]/td[2]
```

but I had no luck..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQuery`, you can simply do the following

```
var anchor = $("a:contains('Example String')");

var requiredTag = anchor.next().next();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried,
>
> //a[contains(., 'Example String')]/td[2]
>
> but I had no luck..

This XPath you are using is trying to select a child of the `a` tag. Since the `a` tag you are looking for is wrapped in a `td` tag, you need to get the parent of `a` and then the sibling `td`:

```
HtmlNode tdNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(., 'Example String')]/parent::*/following-sibling::td[2]");

string tdText = tdNode.InnerText;
```